# Why is \\? being added to my site physical path in IIS?

Tags: iis, web-config

In IIS, I have set my site's physical path to J:\MyFolder\MySite.

When I try to load the site in my browser, I get this error message: [IIS site error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iai2w.png).
Notice that
`\\?`
has been prepended to my path for the Config File setting (red)

Further to this, if I select the site in IIS and try to access an IIS feature, for example the "Default Document" feature, I get this error popup: [IIS feature error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQy7T.png).
Again you can see the
`\\?`
was added.

*Can anybody please advise why this is appearing, where it is set (and how I remove it), and any insight into how I can get my site to load?*

**INFO OF NOTE**

- IIS Version 1607
- OS Version Windows Server 2016 Datacentre

I have other sites running successfully, set up in an identical manner, also within /MyFolder/. I am confident the web.config file itself is not corrupt.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I've tried restarting the site in IIS. I've tried deleting the site in IIS and adding it again. The physical path is absolutely correct. I have compared my web.config file to another site that works to see if there's anything fundamentally different, and there appears to not be.

**WHAT I EXPECT**

I expect the site to load as normal.

I was surprised to not be able to find any answer to a previous question referencing
`\\?`
so I feel posting my own question is the only way forward.

Thankyou in advance for any light you can shine on this.

Comment: You simply cannot delete that from the error page, and there is nothing wrong showing file paths in that format (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#dos-device-paths). The actual error 500.19 is caused by OOB, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: @Lex Li - Thankyou Lex these links are most enlightening

Comment: It looks like some configuration section is not recognized by IIS in the web.config. So please check if you have missed any IIS feature or URL rewrite module.